# Rails 3 i need some help with making a FAQ page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

first off ive tried google and cant seem to find an answer i can understand what i would like to do is list my questions from an active record witch i have that much working then make the question its self a link so her is my page so far!

```
   <h1>Listing faqs</h1>

<table>

<% @faqs.each do |faq| %>
  <tr><td width="90px"><div id="right">Question : </div></td><td><%= faq.question %></td></tr> 

<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<table>

<% @faqs.each do |faq| %>
  <tr><td width="90px"><div id="right">Question : </div></td><td><%= faq.question %></td></tr>
  <tr><td valign="top"><div id="right">Answer : </div></td><td><%= faq.answer %></td></tr>  
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Faq', new_faq_path %>
```

im amusing`enter code here` i can stick something in before faq.question like a link_to or something or something but im not shure what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in Rails 3 forms should start with **<%=**, not **<%**.

```
<%= @faqs.each do |faq| %>
  <tr>
    <td width="90px">
      <div id="right">Question : </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to(faq.question, faq_path(faq.id) %>
    </td>
  </tr> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: just fyi the <% @faqs.each do |faq| %> was done by scaffold but i'll fix it since you told me about it :) do i need to put anything on the lower 1/2 where my question and answers are? so it knows where its linking or is rails just that smart?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using Rails 3, then?  Rails 2 had forms start with <% whereas Rails 3 with <%=.  The lines above in code show how to start the form and how to do a link.  Change the Q&A section in the same manner.

Comment: i have to use the new routing and if you put in the <%= i get #<Faq:0xa4ee288>#<Faq:0xa4ecf80> on the screen. Also i wanted it to link within the page but i guess this will work until i find out how to link within the page!

Comment: Sorry, the link should be link_to(faq.question, faq_path(faq.id)

Comment: thx for the help its not exactly what i wanted but it dose work but now i know what to look for in my searches to get it exactly what i want!